# Universal redux: browserhistory error: cannot read property 'listen' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I'm trying to implement universal rendering for my react-redux app using express.js server, i'm following the tutorial on: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

whenever i try to import the rootreducer or App files into the express server.js file as described in the tutorial i get the following error:

```
\node_modules\react-router-redux\lib\sync.js:105
 unsubscribeFromHistory = history.listen(handleLocationChange);
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'listen' of undefined
at syncHistoryWithStore (C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\citydrill\node_modules\react-router-redux\lib\sync.js:105:35)
```

This is my store file relevant code:

```
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
));

export const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);
```

Then i just use the history const in the clientApp like this:

```
const router = (
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route name="Home" path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute name="Home" component={Landing}></IndexRoute>
        </Route>
    </Router>
</Provider>
```

)

I tried so many different tutorials other than the one in redux.js.org too and i'm always stuck at this one point because i always must import some file from my client code inside my express server.js file and whenever i do that i always end up getting the same error.

How can i implement universal redux? what am i doing wrong? i followed so many tutorials and none of them mentioned this error, how come its working for these guys but not in my app?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `browserHistory` on the server-side, as the name indicates it is for browsers. Use `memoryHistory` instead:

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

Comment: It's not very elaborate on that site, can you share an example?